# How would args be defined in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Essentially, I have a Command that is supposed to Purge Messages/Flood chat (Its for a friend, dont ask), however I keep getting error about args not defined, how would I go and solve the problem?

Background: I have been patching up my spaggehti code (alot of bot.on and if/else strings), and have been trying args, however args do not define and const will not work.

```
{
   if(message.content == '^immigrantalert')
   require ;amount = parseInt(args[0]);
   if (isNaN(amount)) {
        return message.reply('Immigrant purges need a god damn number after the command you twat');
   }
 else if (amount < 2 || amount > 100) {
  return message.reply('you need to input a number between 2 and 100 for Deportation you smack.');
  message.channel.bulkDelete(amount);
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
  message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
};
```

Expected output is the Message Purge and flood to come on upon the command being said, however the output is a crash in my terminal which results in code not working.

Comment: What is calling that code in question? Is this inside of a function that you're passing `args` to? Is `args` actually defined?

Comment: The problem is that I'm unsure on how to define args, I wasn't sure what code I should add for reference, but the problem is the defination

Comment: Is this the entire file? This looks like it wouldn't even compile. The first `if` statement seems to be doing nothing, closing brackets for the last `elif` are missing... you need to provide more context.

Comment: This isn't the entire file, @Geekfish, this the `args` part only, I am only looking on how to correctly define args.

Comment: This should all be in the docs https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html

Generally you should provide code that is contextually "complete", if you provide code that has structural problems then it's very hard for people to read it and figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Geekfish Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
  let command = '^immigrantalert';
  if(message.content.includes(command)) { //look for command in message

     //check the end of the message for the amount
     let amount = parseInt(message.content.slice(command.length));

    if (isNaN(amount)) {
           return message.reply('Immigrant purges need a god damn number after the command you twat');
    } else if (amount < 2 || amount > 100) {
       message.reply('you need to input a number between 2 and 100 for Deportation you smack.');
      message.channel.bulkDelete(amount);
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
      message.reply('RULE BRITANNIA')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your code `const args = message.content.slice(client.config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();`